# Как заменить оперативку на iMac 21.5 2015

Tags: mac, apple

Привет всем! Вопрос немного не по теме, но все таки вы поняли его из тайтла. Мне надо добавить оперативной памяти в этот самый iMac. На сайте Apple пишется, что на этой модели нельзя заменить память, но я этому не верю. Подскажите как сделать это именно на этой модели, и если можно, то скиньте видос как это делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В iMac 21.5 2015 оперативная память впаяна в материнскую плату. Насколько мне известно, некоторые сервисы меняют, но не дают гарантии стабильной работы.

> Как стало известно благодаря специалистам Other World Computing (OWC),
>   в новом iMac оперативная память впаяна непосредственно в материнскую
>   плату, по аналогии с новыми MacBook Air и MacBook Pro Retina. Это
>   означает, что пользователи не смогут просто заменить модули памяти на
>   более емкие при необходимости, что вряд ли можно назвать оптимальным
>   вариантом для стационарного компьютера.

Comment: Жаль. Думал расширить, а не выйдет.